# Bind and Highlight Specific DataGridView Row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am binding data from excel file in a list on button click and this works perfectly. Finally the data is binded to a `DataGridView`. Now I want to iterate the list to check if there are any data that isn't included to the database after binding to a `DataGridView`. If any data mismatches, then it should highlight the specific row with red color in the `DataGridView`. Note: There could be multiple data that will not match. Something as the below image and the code tried:

```
grdUpload.Rows.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < lstData.Count; i++) //lstData - The Data List
{
    if (Facede.ExcelUpload.CheckIfExists(lstData)) //Checking if any data mismatches
    {
       grdUpload.DataSource = lstData;
       grdUpload.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; //Highlight the row data that mismatches
    }
    else
    {
       grdUpload.DataSource = lstData;
    }
}

public bool CheckIfExists(List<Data> lst)
{
   bool flag = false;

   foreach (Data d in lst)
   {
      string Query = "SELECT M.EmpNo FROM Data m WHERE M.EmpNo = '" + d.EmpNo + "'";
      DataTable dt = SelectData(Query);

       if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
          flag = true;
       }
       else
       {
          flag = false;
       }
   }

   return flag;
}
```

Now the issue is it doesn't highlight the specific row if data like EmpNo mismatches. Anything that I am missing here?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Firstly why you always bind data to dgv in foreach loop with this line: `grdUpload.DataSource = lstData;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your `for` loop.

You are firstly binding data to your datagridview.

Then you are entering for loop

Inside it you ask if condition is met and if it is you AGAIN bind same data to datagridview but after it you color it.

For loop continues and it again enters part where it meets condition and AGAIN you BIND same data but now you overwrite colored data with new (but same) data and then color some new row.

So what you need to do is

- Load data into datagridview
- Loop through datagridviewrows and if meet condition color that row

So code should look like this:

```
//Here you bind your data to datagridview
//In code bellow if you want to get row's column's data use 
//row.Cells["CELL_VALUE"].Value (convert to what datatype you need before comparing)

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (condition)))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```